# How many streams does Tor attach to the same circuit?

Tags: circuit, stream-isolation

How many streams does Tor attach to the same circuit, i.e. when Tor think that it is a time to build a new circuit?

I know that the lifetime of a circuit is 10 minutes (for new connections). But before that 10 minutes, can we attach all the coming streams to that circuit or there is a limitation on the number of streams?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any limit other than inherited from [the protocol](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/blob/36761c7d553df7b0160bd1180c19b4a58362c827:/tor-spec.txt#l1202), i.e. 2^16.

[The code](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/tor-0.2.4.19:/src/or/connection_edge.c#l1683) does suggest that all stream IDs (other than 0) are acceptable for streams.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the number of streams in a circuit, but not every stream 'fits' every circuit. If a new stream needs to connect to an IP:port that your existing circuit(s) can't handle, because the exit node rejects it, you need to build a new circuit.